# Flutter Web app not working on IOS 12.5.4 in Iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, flutter, safari, mobile-safari, flutter-web

I am using **Flutter v2.2** with **Firebase (v9)** as a backend for building my Web app, When I build and deploy for web it works fine in Android, Windows browser and also in Iphone 6s browser(both safari/chrome) but isn't working in Iphone 6 plus (IOS 12.5.4) real device in chrome/safari.

Is there any configuration changes required to run in flutter web app on IOS device having version
below 13 which I didnt followed.
My **`flutter doctor -v`** output looks like:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165], locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (10 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Neha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.1)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.31613.86
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Neha\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version
      10.0.19043.1165]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 93.0.961.38

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on what's "not working" on your app when run on a browser using a physical iOS device? Here's a guide on [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Omatt the problem is that the app doesnt show anything in IOS web either chrome or safari  it just loads and shows a white blank page and nothing else but when I run the same app it works in android and web and displays the page properly

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @BermjlyTeam nope the web app still doesn't open up or you can say it is showing full blank white page rather than my home page... any idea what could be wrong or does iphone 6 plus doesn't support some canvas painting technique of flutter

Comment: I haven't debugged this since some time. But I think deep linking might be the issue who knows.

Comment: I faced similar issue in iPhone 6s, and switching to html web-renderer fixed it for me.